# Generic Connector Communication Error in Tomcat 8.5, BonCode AJP Connector

Tags: tomcat, apex, iis-8.5

So I have an ORDS 3.0 application installed on Tomcat 8/BonCode AJP connector/IIS 8.5 setup. I enabled SSO and SSL and everything was working fine. Now, all of a sudden, without any changes made I started receiving `Generic Connector Communication Error` error when accessing any application on Tomcat, not just ords.

The error I get in the browser is:

> Generic Connector Communication Error:
>   Please check and adjust your setup:
>       Ensure that Tomcat is running on given host and port.
>       If this is a timeout error consider adjusting IIS timeout by changing executionTimeout attribute in web.config (see manual).

I looked on the server in Tomcat directory under `logs` folder and found the following warning:

> The web application [ords] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

That is the only thing I can see. I have searched everywhere and tried different tweaks but cannot figure out the solution.

Comment: What version of BonCode are you using? Please post your BonCodeAJP13.settings file - there are other parameters that may be relevent eg MaxConnections etc

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved the issue by making changes to `server.xml` file located in `conf` directory under Tomcat home directory. The `<Connector>` for pot 8080 only needed 4 attributes:  port, redirectPort, connectionTimeout, and protocol. All other to be removed. Also the AJP Connector tag on port 8009 only need 3 attributes: port, protocol, and redirectPort

Comment: changed what? as-is the answer is not likely to help someone with a similar issue.

Comment: Please post your Tomcat server.xml file - there are other parameters that may be relevent eg packetSize, maxThreads